# I am looking for a detailed description on why this code is doing what it does?

Tags: python

(CO 5) What is the value of the total variable after the following code executes?

No background

```
prices=[66, 22, 47, 30]
total = 0
i=1
while i<len(prices):
     total+=prices[i]
     i+=1
print(total)
```

66

0

35

99

99

is the answer i know that. I am just looking for the explanation of why?

Comment: Array index starts at 0. Since `i=1`. it sum `22+47+30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing starts at 0. That's it. That means that the `0`th element is the first element, the `1`st is the second, and so on. Why this is the case is something I'm not sure of, but it's probably because we can get the last item by doing `prices[-1]`.

If we follow along, it gets `prices[1]` first, which is `22`. Next is `47`, and last is `30`. Add them together and it's `99`.

Comment: I knew it was something dumb I just wasn't understanding thanks, man.